# In-memory table performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, memory-optimized-tables

I hope someone can help me troubleshoot the cause of the sudden drop in Transaction created/sec, batch request/sec and the slow performance of in-mem table.

This is a POC exercise - I am trying to evaluate how I could scale up our system workload using in-Mem tables.

**Requirement**

The application has a number of queues. Each queue is assigned to a Windows process that processes the records from WorkQueueItem table (

```
WHERE[BPAInMemWorkQueueItem].[queueident]=@queueid
            AND [BPAInMemWorkQueueItem].deferred < getutcdate()
            AND [BPAInMemWorkQueueItem].[locktime] IS NULL
```

) based on order "priority,loaded,ident". The Windows process constantly queries the table by executing the SP to get the next record to process. At the same time, a number of processes will be inserting data into the WorkQueueItem table.

Our current process works smoothly for up to 500 windows Client processes, anything above that we get performance issues.

When run for 60 sec on a single thread, our present disk-based table implementation processes nearly 6k records. However, the in-mem table implementation process only 2.5k records..Why ?

We are trying to scale this up to the 20k Windows process, hence the in-mem tables.

**Test**

To test the script I loaded 1000000 records into the table. The columns used in the WHERE clause has the default value of queueident=9,deferred ='1900-01-01 00:00:000',deferred =null.

I originally had the following nonclustered index. But the sys.dm_db_xtp_index_stats was showing no usage of the index, hence I dropped. Also, when the index was in place the query plan was showing Table scan instead of Index Scan.

```
INDEX INDEX_BPAInMemWorkQueueItem_queueident_deferred NONCLUSTERED    ([queueident],[deferred],[locktime],[ident])
```

Question 1: From the index and Hash bucket point of view all looks fine to me. What could be causing the drop in the Transaction created/sec and the batch request/sec? How can I troubleshoot it?

Question 2: After the deployment of the natively compiled sp, the ROW_RETURNED column showing an increase. What could be causing this increase?

**Table schema**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BPAInMemWorkQueueItem]
(
    [ident] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED  HASH WITH (BUCKET_COUNT=1048576),
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [queueid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [keyvalue] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [status] [nvarchar](255) NULL CONSTRAINT DF_BPAInMemWorkQueueItem_Status DEFAULT '',
    [attempt] TINYINT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_BPAInMemWorkQueueItem_Attempt DEFAULT ((0)),
    [loaded]  DATETIME2(0) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_BPAInMemWorkQueueItem_Loaded  DEFAULT (GETUTCDATE()),
    [completed]  DATETIME2(0) NULL ,
    [deferred]  DATETIME2(0) NULL CONSTRAINT DF_BPAInMemWorkQueueItem_deferred  DEFAULT '1900-01-01 00:00:00',
    [worktime] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT DF_BPAInMemWorkQueueItem_worktime DEFAULT ((0)),
    [queueident] SMALLINT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_BPAInMemWorkQueueItem_queueident DEFAULT ((0)),
    [sessionid] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [priority] [SMALLINT] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_BPAInMemWorkQueueItem_priority DEFAULT ((0)),
    [prevworktime] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_BPAInMemWorkQueueItem_prevworktime DEFAULT ((0)),
    [attemptworktime]  AS ([worktime]-[prevworktime]),
    [encryptid] [int] NULL,
    [lastupdated]  AS (ISNULL([completed],[loaded])) PERSISTED,
    [locktime] DATETIME2(0) NULL,
    [lockid] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NULL,
    INDEX INDEX_BPAInMemWorkQueueItem_priority_loaded_ident  NONCLUSTERED (  priority asc,[loaded]asc,[ident]asc)
)
with (memory_optimized=on, durability=schema_and_data);
go
```

The following is small portion of the SP that gets executed based on the input parameter.

**Select**

```
SELECT TOP (1) @identout=[ident]
        FROM    dbo.BPAInMemWorkQueueItem
        WHERE   [BPAInMemWorkQueueItem].[queueident]=@queueid
            AND [BPAInMemWorkQueueItem].deferred < getutcdate()
            AND [BPAInMemWorkQueueItem].[locktime] IS NULL
        ORDER BY  priority,loaded,ident;
IF @identout >0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.BPAInMemWorkQueueItem    
            SET [locktime]=GETUTCDATE(),
                [lockid]=NEWID()
        WHERE BPAInMemWorkQueueItem.[ident] =@identout

        select i.encryptid, i.id, @identout ident, i.keyvalue, [bimwqid].[datapayload] [data], i.status, i.attempt
        from dbo.[BPAInMemWorkQueueItem] i
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[BPAInMemWorkQueueItemData] AS [bimwqid] ON [bimwqid].[WQIident] = [i].[ident]
        WHERE i.ident=@identout  
    END
```

**sys.dm_db_xtp_hash_index_stats and sys.dm_db_xtp_index_stats** 
[image]

PerfMon

[image]
[Full Execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1t6qq16U)

Comment: I'm not  clear on if this is a proof-of-concept, or a live environment. 

Questions/statements:

1. why are you using native compilation? I ask because the only type of JOIN that's supported is nested loop

2. Native compilation = single threaded, parallelism is NOT supported

3. Would like to see the entire stored procedure

4. How many concurrent threads are executing?

Comment: Its POC, but if works well we are planning to implement it on Live.I have attached the Query plan link that will show the full sp

Comment: Hekaton is designed to optimize concurrent writes. Having had a look at the attached proc, I see only a single UPDATE, at the end. Queries against memory-optimized tables will not generally be any faster than against traditional tables. 

Add to that the inability to go parallel for a natively compiled proc, and I can't see how this fits the intended design of the feature.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain the full requirement. We need to process the data from the table based on the priority,loaded,ident order. In the real world scenario, this sp will be executed simultaneously by a number of client processes, we are aiming for 20K+ concurrent sessions.

Comment: Edited the post to include the full requirement.

Comment: Hekaton is meant to solve concurrency/blocking issues caused by writer vs. writer, as read/write concurrency issues can by solved by RCSI. 

Even with your expanded details, I would find it hard to believe that Hekaton would help. Additionally, you with native, you reduce the TSQL possibilities and remove parallelism. Just can't see how this will order the orders-of-magnitude perf gains that Hekaton is capable of. Perhaps your testing will reveal otherwise.

Comment: And what you described is essentially a queue, which Hekaton cannot possibly do properly, due to no locks being held.

Comment: That last comment was assuming that 20k concurrent connections would be tryingn to read/process from the queue.